# Count Pixel probability in image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, distribution

I have one signed 16 bit image (pixel range from 0 to over 256). I want to count probability of pixel and save to file. How to do it in matlab. I try to do it by my code. But it is not successfull. My style is

```
Pixel Value   | Prob
          1   | 0.1
          2   | 0.2
          3   | 0.03
    ...
```

This is my code

```
im=imread('test.bmp');
im=double(im);
[m n]=size(im);
p=zeros(2,max(im(:)));
im=im(:);
imsort=sort(im);
for j=1:max(imsort(:))
    p(1,j)=j;
    count=sum(j==im(:));
    p(2,j)=count/(m*n);
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/histc.html):

```
values = (0:2^16-1).';
count = histc(im(:), values);
prob = count/sum(count);
```

The result in the desired format would be

```
result = [values prob];
```

Comment: Thank Sir, But I want to save in one array with 2 columns.And I fixed it by my style. Is it correct? Thank

Answer (score 1):

To save histogram result as a text file

```
save(filename, variable,'ascii');
```